# Создание ветки только измененных файлов в GIT или SVN

Tags: git, svn, контроль-версий, git-branch

Есть проект, в котором N - файлов. Периодически создается версия обновления, но в обновление входят только измененные файлы. Хотим проект завести под систему контроля версий, типа git или svn.

Ищем решение, при котором можно было бы выделить все измененные файлы (например из истории коммитов) автоматически вынесить их в отдельную ветку/branch.

Подскажите, возможно ли такое?

Comment: так вам нужен только список изменившихся файлов или ещё нужны и какие-то изменения в репозитории? более коротко: создание ветки — обязательное условие?

Comment: Создание ветки - обязательное условие (как "рабочей версии"), но после выноса в отдельную ветку, как вариант можно выгрузить изменения как указал alexander barakin либо svn/git export (changes)

Comment: а как насчёт истории? ведь 1. если в этой ветке должна быть только часть файлов, то история всех остальных должна быть удалена, верно? это значит, что новая ветка должна начинаться «с нуля» и не будет «пересекаться» с остальной разработкой, т.е. это будет как бы два (и больше) отдельных репозитория внутри основного репозитория. технически это, конечно, возможно, но, может быть, имеет смысл не другую ветку делать, а **действительно** отдельный репозиторий? (продолжение в следующем комментарии).

Comment: 2. требуется ли в новой ветке (репозитории) сохранять всю историю попавших в неё файлов? или достаточно будет одного коммита, отражающего текущее (на момент создания) состояние файлов?

Comment: 1. история должна сохраниться.
2. в ветку желательно вынести только измененные (отфильтрованные по какому либо признаку) файлы - чтобы знать, что именно попало в обновление.
Может быть такой вариант: текущее состояние проекта помечается тегом (например v1.0), все комиты под этим тегом, которые необходимо вынести в обновление автор помечает в комментарии (например ключевое слово [update]). после того, как решили что версию пора обновлять, делам ветку от тега, а из этой ветки делаем экспорт файлов по ключевому слову.

Comment: я дополнил ответ, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, мне кажется, условие выдвинуто человеком, знакомым с *svn*, но слабо знакомым с *git-ом*, в частности с тем моментом, что в *git-е* ветка (branch) — это «скользящий» указатель на коммит, не более того (это я для автора вопроса упоминаю).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, проблема распространённая. чем смогу — готов помочь, но пользы от меня, боюсь, мало: мой английский хромает, как безногий ветеран ватерлоо.

Comment: Похоже на [проблему XY](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/181472)

Answer (score 6):

**о создании ветки — см. ниже**

### простое решение

если создавать ветку не требуется, а надо лишь получить список файлов, изменившихся между коммитом1 и коммитом2, то можно сделать примерно так:

```
$ git log --name-only --pretty="format:" коммит1..коммит2 | grep -v '^$' | sort -u
```

пояснения:

- `--name-only` — выводить ещё и имена изменённых файлов
- `--pretty="format:"` — вся служебная информация будет выведена как пустые строки
- `grep -v '^$'` — удалит эти пустые строки
- `sort -u` — удалит дубликаты из списка

---

из получившегося списка можно сразу и архив получить. примерно так (сжатый архив запишется в файл `/tmp/archive.tgz`):

```
$ tar -czf /tmp/archive.tgz $(git log --name-only \
 --pretty="format:" коммит1..коммит2 | grep -v '^$' | sort -u)
```

---

ещё про «красоту»: файлы в архиве будут иметь тот же путь, что и в репозитории:

```
dir1/file1
file2
```

чтобы файлы в архиве «лежали» в каталоге, например, `proga-1.0`:

```
proga-1.0/dir1/file1
proga-1.0/file2
```

можно команде *tar* добавить опцию `--transform` (поддерживается, насколько мне известно, только версией *tar* из операционной системы *gnu*):

```
$ tar -czf /tmp/archive.tgz --transform "s,^,proga-1.0/," $(git log
 --name-only --pretty="format:" коммит1..коммит2 | grep -v '^$' | sort -u)
```

### репозиторий со скриптами

предложенные выше «однострочники» я поместил в [репозиторий](https://github.com/sash-kan/strangegitfilter) под лицензией [*gplv3*](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html).

**getfiles [ revision..range ]** — выдаёт список всех файлов, изменявшихся в промежутке *revision..range*. если аргумент пропущен, то скрипт выдаст список всех файлов.

**createarchive revision..range /path/to/archive.tgz [ prefix ]** — создаёт указанный архив (см. выше). если указан *prefix*, он добавляется к именам файлов (слэш в конце префикса автоматически добавляется при необходимости).

**truncatehistory [ revision..range ]** — удаляет из репозитория историю всех файлов, кроме тех, что изменялись в указанный *revision..range*. ***используйте с осторожностью!*** код этого скрипта базируется на [вот этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6006679/4827341).

### о создании ветки

обрезать историю только для одной ветки, не затрагивая остальные, несколько более сложное решение, чем предложенное ниже.

а предлагаю я «обреза́ть» историю не в основном репозитории, а в отдельном его клоне. если возникнет необходимость видеть «обрезанную» историю в своём же репозитории — можно подключить «обрезанный» клон как второй *remote*. учтите, что история у всех файлов из этого клона **полностью** отлична от истории файлов в основном репозитории — начиная с самого первого коммита. поэтому вливать такой отдельно-стоящий набор коммитов в рабочий репозиторий я бы не рекомендовал: теоретически могут возникнуть проблемы с последующей жизнедеятельностью репозитория.

1. скачайте файлы или склонируйте мой [репозиторий](https://github.com/sash-kan/strangegitfilter) со скриптами. путь к скриптам обозначим как */путь1*
2. сделайте клон вашего репозитория в пустом каталоге:

   ```
   $ git clone адрес-вашего репозитория .
   ```
3. запустите:

   ```
   /путь1/truncatehistory revision..range
   ```
4. всё, история репозитория **полностью** переписана и включает только те файлы, которые изменялись в промежутке *revision..range*

Comment: И не только теоретически, а вполне даже практически возникнут проблемы =) . Отличный ответ, даже репозиторий с решениями есть.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну меня заинтересовала задача, в чисто академическом смысле, ведь я прекрасно понимаю как бесполезность, так и малоосмысленность таких требований.

Comment: ну, патчи-то делать — вполне полезная задача, на мой взгляд. А вот обдирать ветки — и правда, бесполезно.

Comment: «обдирать ветки» — хорошая формулировка, надо запомнить.

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваши комментарии. Условия выдвинуты от людей, которые сейчас работают со starteam и попросили проанализировать переход на git. Вот и пришлось "покрутить" с разными вариантами.

Comment: @Anatoly, вероятно, в этом *starteam* термин «ветка» имеет совершенно иное значение. отсюда и «странность» требований («странность» — с точки зрения знакомых с `git`-ом). я думаю, необходимо более формальное (без употребления терминов, имеющих разное значение в разных реализациях vcs) изложение требований. побеседуйте с заказчиками и задайте новый вопрос на основе полученной информации.

Answer (score 2):

1. Вариант действий для **любой SCM** неверен методологически - предлагается дублировать информацию, и так имеющуюся в системе (коллекция измененных объектов между двумя метками в истории)
2. Опять же любая SCM посредственно/плохо подходит для цели "хранилище коллекций артефактов", для этого есть более другие системы

Чисто технически ничто не мешает для любого диапазона истории (в *любой* на выбор VCS) получать динамически список затронутых файлов для включения в патч-лист (команды будут различаться, но не методология), но правильнее - не адаптрировать возможности новой VCS под старый процесс, а переосмыслить процесс и возможно его изменить (хранение патчей в репо выглядит бессмысленной тратой времени и трудозатрат - натуральнее выглядит тегирование **полного дерева** и получение патча для деплоя обновления между тэгами, и это - не зависит от того, какая VCS используется)

Ну и чисто рекомендация - не надо гнаться за модным и бежать на Git, хотя со ST уходить все же разумное решение