# Как упростить задачу для Git с множеством репозииториев?

Tags: git, git-remote

У меня есть 1 проект и я клонировал его в 5 репозиториев.

Каждая репозитория теперь как одно отдельное приложение.

Вопрос.

Если найдется баг или какая то фича которую надо будет добавить во все проекты. Чтобы для каждого репозитория вручную это не делать, то можно ли как то ускорить этот процесс. Через Git?

Comment: звучит сложновато, но наверно все равно через скрипт. Например так: Изменение в файле, делаем add в одном из репозиториев. Затем скрипт проходит по ветке и смотрит ага, изменение тут и копирует его. Затем добавляет его во все остальные ветки по циклу и применяет add там. Но это костыльное решение

Comment: Сомнительно, что вам нужно пять репозиториев. Если различия только в конфигах, то вам нужен только один проект, если есть общее ядро, то нужно отрефакторить.

Comment: если приложения однотипные и имеют в базе одно и то же кодовое ядро, то может быть проще было настроить [Product Flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors), вместо тиражирования реп?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### если это действительно клоны одного общего хранилища

(и создавались командой `git clone` или с помощью какой-нибудь «обёртки», которая и выполняла эту команду), то внести изменения можно в любом из клонов, затем командой `git push` отправить эти изменения в общее хранилище, а в остальных клонах получить эти изменения командой `git pull`.

---

проверить, связан ли клон с общим хранилищем, можно примерно так:

```
$ git remote
```

покажет список псевдоним для подключенных хранилищ. например:

```
origin
```

дальше можно посмотреть *url* этого хранилища:

```
$ git remote show origin
```

пример вывода (про хранилище, созданное для [ответа на один здешний вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/434548/178576)):

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:sash-kan/strangegitfilter.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:sash-kan/strangegitfilter.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

#### если хранилища никак не связаны

то можно воспользоваться программой *git* как некой «обёрткой» вокруг программ *diff* и *patch* (см. команды `diff`, `log` (с опцией `-p`), `format-patch`, `apply`).

например, имеется коммит (с таким-то хэшем), в котором внесены изменения, которые требуется применить в нескольких других (аналогичных по структуре каталогов) хранилищах:

1. получаем набор изменений («diff»), внесённых этим коммитом:

   ```
   $ git log -n 1 -p хэш-коммита > /путь/к/файлу/с/изменениями
   ```

   1. если изменения зафиксированы несколькими подряд идущими коммитами, можно увеличить число после опции `-n`, тогда будут сохранены изменения, произошедшие в указанном числе коммитов, начиная с указанного хэшем и дальше по истории (как она отображатеся командой `log`)
   2. если коммитов несколько, но они идут не подряд, можно добавить к файлу изменения и из других коммитов (обратите внимание на другой оператор перенаправления — `>>` вместо `>`):

      ```
      $ git log -n 1 -p хэш-другого-коммита >> /путь/к/файлу/с/изменениями
      ```
2. делаем текущим рабочий каталог другого хранилища, в котором пока нет этих изменений:

   ```
   $ cd /путь/к/каталогу
   ```
3. применяем изменения, сохранённые на первом шаге:

   ```
   $ git apply /путь/к/файлу/с/изменениями
   ```
4. если возникли конфликты, то устраняем их
5. делаем коммит для этих изменений
6. повторяем шаги 2-5 для остальных хранилищ

Comment: Берем любой проект. Делаем копипаст в 3 репозитория.

После дополняем всякие фичи у всех репозиториев свои будут.

Спустя месяц Я нашел баг в 1 репозитории, я его исправил. Вопрос как мне это дело перенести во 2 и 3 репозитории?

Просто чтобы не делать 3 работу, можно облегчить сие дело как то через Git вот в чем вопрос

Comment: @xTIGRx, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо.________