# Как передать коммит в другой репозиторий?

Tags: android, git

У меня есть 2 репозитория. A и B

В A я создал коммит. Как мне передать этот коммит в репозиторий B?

Если можно средствами Android Studio. Спасибо

Comment: Репозитории между собой как-то связаны? Есть ли в В уже какие-то коммиты?

Comment: Оба репозитория созданы у вас (или у коллеги) на рабочей машине или один из них на GitHub, GitLab или подобном им сайте?

Comment: это же практически [другой ваш вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/684885/178576)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да это точно тот же.