# Расширенный патч в git

Tags: git

Если тебе необходимо перенести изменения из репозитория в репозиторий, то ты используешь `git diff -> git apply`.

Но в случае, если репозитории отличаются слишком сильно, ты получишь гору ошибок. 
Есть ли возможность в гите создать расширенный патч, который будет содержать не изменения данного коммита в сравнении с прошлым коммитом, а сами файлы, задетые этим коммитом?

Ну, чтобы даже применив такой патч на абсолютно пустой репозиторий, там бы появились все файлы, задетые в коммите в репозитории-доноре. (Но не весь репозиторий-донор! Только файлы задетые в одном коммите!)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/434548/178576

Comment: патч - это изменения между двумя состояниями файла. если хоть одно из этих состояний не известно (т.е., произвольно), то и патч соответствующий создать невозможно. вам нужен не патч, а актуальное полное содержимое требуемых файлов. как их получить, описано по ссылке из предыдущего моего комментария.

Answer (score 1):

> Есть ли возможность в гите создать расширенный патч, который будет содержать не изменения данного коммита в сравнении с прошлым коммитом, а сами файлы, задетые этим коммитом?

то, что вы описали, называется не «патч», а «непосредственно содержимое файлов». ведь «патч» — это разница между двумя конкретными состояниями файла(-ов), а если одно из состояний неизвестно, как в вашем случае, то и получить «патч» (разницу) становится методологически невозможно.

я уже давал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/434548/178576) на подобный вопрос (ваш вопрос фактически является его под-вопросом). привожу только команду, подробности смотрите в [том ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/434548/178576):

```
$ tar -czf /tmp/archive.tgz $(git log --name-only \
 --pretty="format:" коммит1..коммит2 | grep -v '^$' | sort -u)
```